# Proper way to use \ensuremath to define a macro useable in and out of math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

Based on this solution [related to defining a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/define-a-macro-via-macro-if-given-macro-is-not-defined) I came up with this macro to help me define a macro that I can use either in or outside of math mode.

The example as is functions as I want. However, this solution requires me to **NOT** put `$$` around the second parameter to to the `\DefineNamedFunction` macro.  I would like to be able to include the $$, or not include it.

One solution is to modify `\DefineNamedFunction` to strip out the `$$` if it is included in the macro call using the `xstring` pacakge, but this to me feels like a hack, and am thinking that there is probably a cleaner TeX way to do this.

So to summarize: How do I change `\DefineNamedFunction` such that I can use both the commented and uncommented calls to this macro, and still be able to use the definition inside and outside of math mode?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\DefineNamedFunction}[2]{% {FunctionName}{FunctionExpression}
    \expandafter\providecommand\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{\textcolor{red}{\ensuremath{#2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\DefineNamedFunction{FunctionF}{y = 2 \sin x}
%\DefineNamedFunction{FunctionF}{$y = 2 \sin x$}

I can use FunctionF inside math mode as $\FunctionF$,
but can also use this outside of math mode as \FunctionF.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably

```
\ensuremath{\textcolor{red}{#2}}
```

is what you need, since `\textcolor` can be used in text and in math. The complete definition is

```
\newcommand{\DefineNamedFunction}[2]{% {FunctionName}{FunctionExpression}
    \expandafter\providecommand\csname#1\endcsname
      {\ensuremath{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}%
}
...
\DefineNamedFunction{FunctionF}{y=2\sin x}
$\FunctionF$ and \FunctionF
```

[image: Sample]

I've also deleted the braces that require another `\expandafter`, but that's not the problem.

Of course, you can't call

```
\DefinedNamedFunction{FunctionFF}{$y=x$}
```

and I wouldn't know why you'd want it. But in any case there's a simple solution

```
\newcommand{\DefineNamedFunction}[2]{%
  \expandafter\providecommand\csname#1\endcsname
    {\ensuremath{\begingroup\color{red}\DNFnorm#2\endgroup}}}
\makeatletter
\def\DNFnorm{\@ifnextchar$\DNFnormi{}}
\def\DNFnormi$#1${#1}
\makeatother
```

The input is "normalized" by removing the `$` tokens before and after, if present.

With `\begingroup\color{red}...\endgroup` the spaces in the subformula participate to the stretching and shrinking of the spaces in the line.

Comment: That does not seem to behave any differently. Yes, in the MWE I should have switched it to `\newcommand`, but I need `\providecommand` in my real usage.

Comment: @Peter: really? To me it does exactly what you want. I'll edit the answer with the complete definition.

Comment: Only reason I would want to be able to call `\DefinedNamedFunction{FunctionFF}{$y=x$}`
 (with the dollar signs) as it is more natural to do so. I didn't want to have to remember that when I use this macro I do not put the `$$`, but for all the other macros where I have math, I do put the `$$`.

Comment: This solution using `DNFnorm` looks simpler.

Comment: @Peter: it's just a command defined for the purpose. It checks whether `#2` starts with `$`; in this case it is substituted by `\DNFnormi` that throws away the two `$`, otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I realized that and tried to edit my comment in time, but you were too quick. Thanks, I can actually understand this solution and customize it for me needs. Works great so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\DefineNamedFunction#1#2{\expandafter\DefineNamedFunction@i#1\@nil#2\@nil}
\def\DefineNamedFunction@i#1\@nil{%
  \@ifnextchar${\DefineNamedFunction@ii{#1}}{\DefineNamedFunction@iii{#1}}}
\def\DefineNamedFunction@ii#1$#2$\@nil{%
  \@namedef{#1}{\ifmmode\textcolor{red}{#2}\else\textcolor{red}{$#2$}\fi}}
\def\DefineNamedFunction@iii#1#2\@nil{%
  \@namedef{#1}{\ifmmode\textcolor{red}{#2}\else\textcolor{red}{$#2$}\fi}}
\makeatother

\DefineNamedFunction{FunctionF}{y = 2 \sin x}
\DefineNamedFunction{FunctionFF}{$y = 2 \sin x$}
\begin{document}    
I can use \FunctionF\ inside math mode as $\FunctionF$,
but can also use this outside of math mode as 
$\FunctionFF$ and \FunctionFF.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks. So, is this basically doing the job of `\ensuremath` manually?

Comment: more or less ... the problem is `\textcolor` when it is used in math mode with a math argument

Comment: @Herbert: apart from making the `+` an ordinary atom, `$\textcolor{blue}{a}\textcolor{red}{+}\textcolor{green}{b}$` works perfectly.

Comment: @egreg: I was talking about `$\textcolor{blue}{$a$}$` ...

Comment: @Herbert: I see; `\textcolor` is smart enough to know when it's called in math mode: maybe a pair `\textcolor` and `\mathcolor` would have been better.

Comment: @egreg: I meant this: `$\DefineNamedFunction{FunctionFFF}{$y = 2 \sin x$}\FunctionFFF$`

Comment: @Herbert: that would be a very devious way. With my macros it works.

Comment: @egreg: I never said, that it wouldn't work with your solution ...