# How to automaticaly add math environment when it's needeed?

Tags: math-mode, environments

I have a command which needs a math environment to be used. 
But sometimes I want to use it in a text environment and so, I need to create the math environment :

```
words words words \( \myFunction \) words words
```

How to detect in which environment I am ?

I want to be able to do :

```
words words words \myFunction words words
```

and

```
\( 1+2 = \myFunction \)
```

Comment: You might be looking for `\ensuremath`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/how-can-i-write-a-macro-which-enters-math-mode-when-called-in-text-mode-but-when/239586#239586 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830

Comment: The test, if you wish to test, is `\ifmmode ...\else ...\fi`