# Setting a common prefix for macro names

Tags: macros, packages, naming

Is it possible to set a common prefix for all macros in a package? Something like:

```
\def\prefix{mypackage}

\newcommand{{\prefix}macroone}{ ... } % does not work, of course
\newcommand{{\prefix}macrotwo}{ ... }
```

One would then call the macros as `mypackagemacroone` and `mypackagemacrotwo`.

Comment: This question on [how to define a macro via a macro if the given macro is not defined might be useful](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/define-a-macro-via-macro-if-given-macro-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\csname <name> \endcsname` to build a `\<name>` macro. You need to expand it first before you feed it to `\newcommand`:

```
\def\prefix{mypackage}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname\prefix macroone\endcsname{ ... }%
```

There is also `\@namedef{<name>}<parameter text>{<expansion text>}` which is simply a `\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname`. You could define your own macro like that which also inserts the prefix:

```
\def\prefix{mypackage}
\def\@pnamedef#1{\expandafter\def\csname\prefix #1\endcsname}
\@pnamedef{macroone}#1{Hello #1 World}
```

If you want to use `\newenvironment` instead to use its does-already-exists check and optional argument use:

```
\newcommand{\pnewcommand}[1]{%
    \@ifstar
        {\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname\prefix #1\endcsname}%
        {\expandafter\newcommand\csname\prefix #1\endcsname}%
}%
\pnewcommand{macroone}[2][]{Hello #2 World #1}
```

Note that names here are only intended as examples and you should be careful which user-level macros (no `@`) you define.

Answer (score 2):

```
\makeatletter
\def\Pnewcommand{\@star@or@long\Pnew@command}
\def\Pnew@command#1{%
  \expandafter\@testopt\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\@newcommand\csname\prefix#1\endcsname}0}
\makeatother

\def\prefix{my}
\Pnewcommand{macro}[1][!]{\message{Argument is #1}}
\Pnewcommand*{macrotwo}[1]{\message{Argument is #1}}

\mymacro
\mymacro[1]

\mymacrotwo{X}
\mymacrotwo{\par} % invalid
```

This hooks directly in the commands linked to `\newcommand`, thus sparing some expansions and assignments with respect to Martin's answer, which is of course more comprehensible. One can also define a `\Prenewcommand`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\Prenewcommand{\@star@or@long\Prenew@command}
\def\Prenew@command#1{%
  \begingroup \escapechar\m@ne
    \xdef\@gtempa{{\expandafter\string\csname\prefix#1\endcsname}}%
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\@ifundefined\@gtempa
     {\@latex@error{\expandafter\noexpand\csname\prefix#1\endcsname undefined}\@ehc}%
     \relax
  \let\@ifdefinable\@rc@ifdefinable
  \Pnew@command{#1}}
\makeatother
```

It's a more or less straightforward rewriting of `\renewcommand` and `\renew@command`. For `\newenvironment` we can say

```
\newcommand{\Pnewenvironment}[1]{\newenvironment{\prefix#1}}
```

and so `\Pnewenvironment{env}{start}{end}` would define the environment `myenv`, if `\prefix` expands to `\my`.