# How to define a macro to create a new macro with a name passed as its argument?

Tags: macros

I want to define a macro `\create` that accept a single mandatory argument from which another new macro is created and named.

The following code snippet may speak clearer what I want to achieve. But the following code cannot be compiled because it is wrong. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\create[1]{%
\newcommand\#1{My name is #1}}

\begin{document}
\create{test}
\test
\end{document}
```

How to define a macro to create a new macro with a name passed as its argument?

Comment: Related to [this question on how to define a macro via a macro if given macro is not defined.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/define-a-macro-via-macro-if-given-macro-is-not-defined)

Comment: @xport Check my code on about line 2 (command factory) at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13333/macros-with-as-the-last-parameter

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `\csname #1\endcsname` which must be expanded before `\newcommand` using `\expandafter`:

```
\newcommand\create[1]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{My name is #1}}
% usage: \create{foobar}
```

If you want to pass the macro as control sequence instead, i.e. `\foobar` instead of `foobar` then you need to turn it into a string and remove the backslash:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\create[1]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\endcsname{My name is #1}}
\makeatother
% usage: \create{\foobar}
```

There is also the `\@namedef` macro which is defined as `\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname`, so you can use it as:

```
\newcommand\create[1]{\@namedef{My name is #1}}
```

The `etoolbox` package also provides a basically identical, but robust macro called `\csdef`. For both you can provide a parameter text, e.g. for arguments direct after the name argument: `\csdef{name}#1#2{some code with two arguments #1 and #2}` (the `#` have to be doubled inside another macro).

Comment: @xport: In this case you must define the macro globally, i.e. either use `\global\@namdef{#1}{<content>}` or, if you need `\newcommand`, `\global\expandafter\let\csname #1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname`.

Comment: @xport: Yes, using \gdef` instead of `\newcommand` will do it as well.

Comment: @xport: You didn't provide the real example to explain why grouping is necessary. There are many tricks to define a macro in group, e.g. `{\def\x{\def\foo{bar}}\expandafter}\x`. But you should firstly persuade us (and yourself) to believe that it is necessary to use these tricks.

Comment: @Leo: If you are interested in avoiding grouping, see [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-larg/25448#25448). I just applied what I learnt from this question.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\create[1]{%                                                         
\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{My name is #1}}

\begin{document}
\create{test}
\test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to be doing lots of this sort of thing, you can create a bunch of macros in one go from a comma separated list with some `etoolbox` magic:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\create[1]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{My name is #1}}
\newcommand\createlist{%
\let\do\create
\docsvlist
}
```

The argument of `\createlist` should be a list like: `\createlist{foo,Foo,magic,jabberwocky}` and it will create `\foo,\Foo,\magic,\jabberwocky`

Comment: With `etoolbox`, you can use `\csdef`, `\csgdef` then.

Comment: @Leo but then you don't have the protection from overwriting definitions that `\newcommand` gives you...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the macro name as a macro name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\create}[1]% #1 = macro name
{\bgroup
  \def\foo{Hello World!}% local definition
  \global\let#1=\foo
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\create{\mymacro}%
\mymacro
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `\newcommand\create[1]{\def#1{Hello World!}}`? Sorry, I don't know much about tex subtleties.

Comment: @coldfix - I knew \let would work.  I wasn't sure about \def, especially if the macro itself has arguments: