# XParse: Command, which creates a command

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

SE, lately I'm playing around with `expl3` and `xparse` a little and I encountered following problem: I want to create a command which creates a new
command -- similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25452/how-to-define-a-macro-to-create-a-new-macro-with-a-name-passed-as-its-argument). This is not as hard, as long the second command doesn't have any arguments; trying to create a command, which accepts arguments is a little more tricky.

What I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{ m}
{
    \NewDocumentCommand#1 {m}
        {My name is \string#1, king of kings}
}

\begin{document}
\test{\ozymandias}
\ozymandias{\manthano}
\end{document}
```

This outputs `My name is ozymandias, king of kings`, which gives the correct sonnet, but not what I wanted. I know where the problem is, I just don't know how to fix it atm :)

Comment: The `\string#1` is unclear! What do you expect this to do?

Comment: The argument in the inner definition should be referred to with `##1`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The `\string#1` was used as an example, basically I just intended to do more complicated stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder about the `\string#1` inside.

The new command inside can be constructed with

```
\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{...}{....}
```

i.e. the name of the new sequence must be constructed first with `\expandafter` (first the name is given, then `\NewDocumentCommand` comes into action). The same approach has to be taken for the traditional `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` etc.

However, the `\test` command must be used as `\test{ozymandias}`, without `\`!

Please note, that it is necessary to use `##1` to access the first argument of the inner macro (if this is wanted at all), subsequent arguments are numbered with `##2` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\manthano}{}{Manthano}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{ m}
{%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{m}{%
   My name is ##1, king of kings%
   }
}

\begin{document}
\test{ozymandias}
\ozymandias{\manthano}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** To use `\test` with `\`, you have to adapt the command to

```
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\test{ m}
{%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string #1\endcsname{m}{%
   My name is ##1, king of kings%
   }
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; the `##1` was indeed on misaing piece of the puzzle. Before I'm accepting you answer, is there a way to write `\test`, so that it processes an argument starting with an `\`? I already tested some combination of `\csname\@gobble\string #1\endcsname` but neither did it work properly nor do I think this is the LaTex3 approach (Btw. this is the reason, why I used the unlucky `\string #1` example here).

Comment: @manthano: Do you mean something like `\test{?ozymandias}` or using the ? as a delimiter, more like `\test?ozymandias?` ???

Comment: Merde, I misspelled it. Somehow I cannot correct my comment on a mobile device, I will come back to it later. What I meant: I want the argument to start with \ and I tested `\csname\@gobble\string #1\endcsname`

Comment: @manthano: Hm, unsure how to achieve this at the moment. Since `xparse` is involved already, `expl3` might come into action!

Comment: I already thought about explicit expl3 usage, but I'm not used to it very well. I'll give it a try. Thank you

Comment: @manthano: The problem with `\test{\foo}` is, that TeX tries to `expand` foo first, before it does anything with the inner `\NewDocumentCommand`

Comment: I managed to fix this and took the liberty to expand your answer.

Comment: @manthano: Ok, I've never thought about this way ;-)