# Define multiple commands based on the same basic command

Tags: macros

I would like to define these commands:

```
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

When I try to use `\green` the output corresponds to the command `\red`. This shows that, other than the last one, the previous definitions are being ignored or replaced by the last one, perhaps because all are based on the same "basic" command, namely `\textcolor`.

**EDIT**

Thank you to all for your answers. Here is a MWE (rather a minimal "not-working" example hehe). It seems that there is indeed a problem with the `cprotect` package, which I need in order to be able to use the `verb` environment inside the macros. Not only the previous macro definitions are being ignored, but the vertical spacing is not being applied, too.

**If the best course of action is to ask a separate question, don't hesitate to tell me.**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor,cprotect}

\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\cMakeRobust\green
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\cMakeRobust\blue
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\cMakeRobust\red

\begin{document}

\green{Huey $e^{\pi i}+1=0$ (math is OK)}\newline

\newline\blue{Dewey \verb|I'm using verbatim here $e^{\pi i}+1=0$|}
\\[3mm]\red{\textbf{Louie}}

\vspace{3mm}\green{Vertical spacing is not working, too.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide complete code. It makes no difference that your definitions are using the same command in their definitions. Unless you redefined `\textcolor` by mistake. You can use it in as many definitions as you wish.

Comment: I’ve wrapped your definitions in a standard preamble, with `\usepackage{color}`, and they work as expected.  You should post a MWE that exhibits the problem you claim to have.

Comment: I just did the same as @GustavoMezzetti just to be absolutely sure. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\green{green} \blue{blue} \red{red} \red{green} \green{blue} \blue{red}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @cfr: Then we are three, as it seems… :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti 1/3 is going to bed now :).

Comment: @cfr Because I intend to use `verb` sometimes inside the macros. Unfortunately, the `verb`environment doesn't work inside macros; solving this is precisely the purpose of the `cprotect`package.

Comment: @cfr You are right, included now.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: I have the impression that `\cMakeRobust` does not maintain the color stack

Comment: Thanks. I would suggest unaccepting the existing answer so people know the problem isn't solved. I don't see much point in a new question because there isn't really a different question here - we were just trying to get clear about what the problem you wanted help with was.

Comment: Related here is the multidef package, e.g. "\usepackage{multidef}\multidef[prefix=cal]{\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}}{G, O, Z}\multidef[noerr,nowarn]{\mathbb{#1}}{A-Z}"   .   See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25452/how-to-define-a-macro-to-create-a-new-macro-with-a-name-passed-as-its-argument

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete code example (what is typically needed here). I do not see any problems.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\green{green} \blue{blue} \red{red}

\end{document}
```

[image]