# How to redefine several commands all at once?

Tags: macros

It happens sometimes that because I deal with complicated formulas, I want to add extra space around certain symbols, e.g. `\longrightarrow, \subset, \cong`, etc.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\let\OLDsubset\subset
\renewcommand{\subset}[1][0]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{\OLDsubset}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\;\OLDsubset\;}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\;\;\OLDsubset\;\;}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{\quad\OLDsubset\quad}{}
}

\begin{document}
$$A \subset B$$
$$A \subset[2] B$$
\end{document}
```

It works well, but my question is the following. Is there a way to create a single 'meta-command' (macro) e.g. `\AddSpace` that takes a command as argument, and then for instance `\AddSpace{\subset}` would produce the above code automatically.

The goal is to be able to use the same code as above for other commands as `\subseteq, \cong` (that do *not* initially take optional arguments, for safety), etc., without having to copy-paste the same piece of code for each of those commands.

I am aware of `multidef` package, but it doesn't seem to be the right tool here. I tried to play around the ideas from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25452), without much success. Maybe with `xparse` package, and `\RenewDocumentCommand`, etc.?

---

NB: I do *not* want to have something like this:

```
\newcommand{\AddMoreSpace}[2][1]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\;#2\;}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\;\;#2\;\;}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{\quad #2 \quad}{}
}
```

because using e.g.

```
$$A \AddMoreSpace{\subset} B$$
$$A \AddMoreSpace[2]{\subset} B$$
```

is too "complicated" / too long to write...

Comment: (Other commands: \cong, \Equal   (create new command for "="), \leq, \geq, \ll, \gg, \to, \mapsto, \into, \longmapsto, \longrightarrow, \implies, \cdot, \Plus (to be created), \oplus, \times, \otimes, ...)

Comment: I don't see why this isn't achievable with a for loop and `\csname` and `\endcsname` to pass the command name as a "string". I would pay attention to global definitions here. You basically want to zip two lists together, one with a command sequence, and one with the spacing category, right? And then redefine accordingly? My knee jerk reaction would tell me to use `LuaLaTeX` because that's my comfort zone.

Comment: I think I initially misunderstood the problem. Disregard all but the first two sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching quite a bit, I finally found a way to solve my problem. Any comment is welcome -- the following MWE might show some "bad practice" (but at least it works!)...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\AddSpace}[1]{
    \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1][0]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{0}}{\csname old#1\endcsname}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{1}}{\;\csname old#1\endcsname\;}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{2}}{\;\;\csname old#1\endcsname\;\;}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{3}}{\quad\csname old#1\endcsname\quad}{}%       
    }%
}

\AddSpace{subset}
\AddSpace{mapsto}


\begin{document}

$a \subset[3] b$

$a \subset b$

$a \mapsto[2] b$

$a \mapsto b$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The command `\;` is shorthand for `\mskip\thickmuskip`, so you can multiply it, instead of adding.

The old command name is saved as `\watson<oldcommand` using a `\csname` trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\AddSpaceToCommand}[1]{%
  \expandafter\NewCommandCopy\csname watson\string#1\endcsname #1%
  \renewcommand#1[1][0]{%
    \mspace{\muexpr\thickmuskip*##1\relax}%
    \csname watson\string#1\endcsname
    \mspace{\muexpr\thickmuskip*##1\relax}%
  }%
}

\AddSpaceToCommand{\subset}
\AddSpaceToCommand{\mapsto}

\begin{document}

$a \subset b$

$a \subset[1] b$

$a \subset[2] b$

$a \subset[3] b$

$a \mapsto b$

$a \mapsto[1] b$

$a \mapsto[2] b$

$a \mapsto[3] b$

\end{document}
```

[image]