# Problem with macro for creating and defining length using \settowidth and then making it an hspace command

Tags: macros

It's in the title. I'm trying to make a command-creating macro which would quickly create a length and setting it to some `\settowidth{}{}` output, then making it a command for horizontal spacing.

I also tried with `\csname#1\endcsname` but it doesn't work either.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\newspace}[2]{%
    \newlength{#1aux}%
    \settowidth{#1aux}{#2}%
    \newcommand{#1}{\hspace*{#1aux}}}

\begin{document}
    
\newspace{\QQspace}{QQ} 

    AQQA
    A\QQspace A
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crux of the answer is given in [How to define a macro to create a new macro with a name passed as its argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25452/106162) with the `#1aux` macro requiring additional `\csname`s and associated `\expandafter`s to ensure the `\csname` happens first.

```
\newcommand{\newspace}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newlength\expandafter{\csname#1aux\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\settowidth\expandafter{\csname#1aux\endcsname}{#2}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{%
        \expandafter\hspace\expandafter*\expandafter{\csname#1aux\endcsname}}}
```

However with the aid of the `calc` package, `\widthof` circumvents a lot of unpleasant boilerplate code

```
\newcommand{\betternewspace}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{\hspace*{\widthof{#2}}}}
```

`\hphantom{#2}` (which doesn't require `calc`) has a similar effect to `\hspace*{\widthof{#2}}` but acts as `\hspace` rather than `\hspace*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\newspace}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newlength\expandafter{\csname#1aux\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\settowidth\expandafter{\csname#1aux\endcsname}{#2}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{\expandafter\hspace\expandafter*\expandafter{\csname#1aux\endcsname}}}
 
\newcommand{\betternewspace}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{\hspace*{\widthof{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
    
\newspace{QQspace}{QQ} 
\betternewspace{QQspaceTwo}{QQ} 
\noindent%
AQQA\\
A\QQspace B\\
A\QQspaceTwo B\\
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled code showing AQQA on one line and a gap equal to QQ between A and B on the second and third lines]

Comment: You're trying to create two distinct macros from a single macro, if `#1` is a macro then  `\newlength{#1aux}` is just going to create a length equal to `#1` (and then do something undesirable with the remaining tokens), to generate a new macro name you'll have to use `\csname` to append the `aux` and you could work around that with `\expandafter\string\@gobble` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25453/106162) but that seems to make life more difficult not less.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to allocate a length: just define `\QQspace` to `\hspace*{<width>}`, where the width can be computed using a scratch length.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newspace}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen@}{#2}%
  \ExpandArgs{ne}\newcommand{#1}{\noexpand\hspace*{\the\dimen@}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newspace{\QQspace}{QQ}

AQQA

A\QQspace A

\texttt{\meaning\QQspace}

\end{document}
```

This uses `\ExpandArgs{ne}` that

1. jumps over the next token, here `\newcommand`;
2. jumps over the next braced argument, because of `n`, here `{#1}`;
3. fully `e`xpands the contents of the next braced argument.

This explains the `\noexpand` in front of `\hspace` and `\the` in front of `\dimen@`.

[image]

With “classic” code, the `\ExpandArgs` line might be

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\newcommand{\noexpand#1}{\noexpand\hspace*{\the\dimen@}}%
}\x
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on `Dai Bowen`'s answer, but restablishing the `backslash` in the argument.

Credit: [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25453/262813).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} % Provides the useful \widthof command.

\makeatletter % Makes the character "@" a normal letter (here needed to call the \@gobble macro).

\newcommand{\newspace}[2]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\endcsname{%
\hspace*{\widthof{#2}}%
                        }%
}

\makeatother % Resets @'s catcode to default.

\begin{document}
    
    \newspace{\QQspace}{QQ} 
    
    AQQA

    A\QQspace A

\end{document}
```