# Defining a newcommand, with variable name, inside another newcommand

Tags: macros

I wish to use `\newcommand` inside `\newcommand`. I can do a basic version of that, but the bit that I can't figure out is how to construct a nontrivial name for the inner `\newcommand` (i.e. by prepending a prefix to the argument of the outer `\newcommand`).

A minimal example to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\defpill}[3]{
  \newcommand{\blue#1}{#2}
  \newcommand{\red#1}{#3}
}

\begin{document}

Let me define a pill (with apologies to chemists).
  \defpill{aspirin}{$A_2Sp_3$}{$A_2Sp_5$}
This should not print anything.

But I should now be able to use my new commands, for example the one
giving the formula of the red aspirin: \redaspirin. Or the blue one:
\blueaspirin.

\end{document}
```

The bit that doesn't work, I suspect, is the variable name of the inner commands (`\blue#1` etc). A simpler example where the name of the inner command is just `#1` works fine, but then I'd have to supply two names instead of having `\defpill` build them for me out of a single suffix.

How do I do that?

Comment: Similar Question: [define a macro via macro if given macro is not defined](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/define-a-macro-via-macro-if-given-macro-is-not-defined)

Comment: @Peter Grill: true, and thanks for the note. I searched before posting but could not find it. In this case I guess the people who can see the similarity are those who already knew the answer!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`\csname` is your friend:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\defpill}[3]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname blue#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname red#1\endcsname{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

Let me define a pill (with apologies to chemists).%
  \defpill{aspirin}{$A_2Sp_3$}{$A_2Sp_5$}
This should not print anything.

But I should now be able to use my new commands, for example the one
giving the formula of the red aspirin: \redaspirin. Or the blue one:
\blueaspirin.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be better to add `%` after the braces in the `\newcommand` to prevent additional spaces being inserted.

Comment: Excellent, thanks knut, just what I needed! You taught me something new.

Comment: @PeterGrill What would happen if *additional spaces* were inserted? And actually, how would they be inserted, and where?

Comment: @Rubens: You can try experimenting and look carefully at the output. Also have a look at [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro).

Answer (score 12):

Based on egreg's answer to my more-complicated issue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34697/variable-name-newcommand-with-parameters-within-another-newcommand), you should also consider using `\@namedef`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defpill}[3]{%
  \@namedef{blue#1}{#2}%
  \@namedef{red#1}{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Let me define a pill (with apologies to chemists).%
  \defpill{aspirin}{$A_2Sp_3$}{$A_2Sp_5$}
This should not print anything.

But I should now be able to use my new commands, for example the one
giving the formula of the red aspirin: \redaspirin. Or the blue one:
\blueaspirin.
\end{document}
```