# Variable-name \newcommand with parameters within another \newcommand

Tags: macros, parameters

In ["Defining a newcommand, with variable name, inside another newcommand"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/) we learned how to use `\newcommand` within a command definition with another `\newcommand`, when the name of the inner command needs to contain a parameter of the outer command. Now, suppose I want to do the same, but for the inner `\newcommand` to also have parameters, i.e. I want the following code to work:

```
\newcommand{\defsilly}[1]{%
  % define a command named silly#1 , taking a single parameter
}
\defsilly{willy}
\sillywilly{theparameter}
```

Motivation: I'm writing a thesis document class, which has a bunch of the following kind of command pairs:

```
\newcommand{\iitthesis@authorEnglish}{Name of Author}
\newcommand{\authorEnglish}[1]{\renewcommand{\iitthesis@authorEnglish}{#1}}
```

I want to replace each of these pairs with something like:

```
\iitthesis@thesisdatafield{authorEnglish}{Name of Author}
```

This defines both the above commands.

Comment: When a `newcommand` is defined within the `newcommand` the inner `newcommand` needs to use `##1` to access its first parameter, as `#1` refers to the parents first parameter.  Also, need to use `makeatletter`, `maketatother` around commands that use an `@` sign in them.

Comment: Please stop calling new commands (macros) as "a `\newcommand`". The `\newcommand` macro defines new commands, but these aren't "a `\newcommand`". What are your trying to do now? Define a new macro given by name (plus prefix) or a new version of `\newcommand`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\iitthesis@thesisdatafield}[2]{%
  \@namedef{iitthesis@#1}{#2}}
```

With

```
\iitthesis@thesisdatafield{authorEnglish}{Name of Author}
```

you'd define `\iitthesis@authorEnglish` to expand to "Name of Author", that is, you'd have issued the equivalent of

```
\def\iitthesis@authorEnglish{Name of Author}
```

This wouldn't check for the defined command to be previously undefined. If you want also this check, do

```
\newcommand{\iitthesis@thesisdatafield}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname iitthesis@#1\endcsname
    {\@namedef{iitthesis@#1}{#2}}}
```

but for internal commands this isn't usually done.

In your motivation I don't see any need of defining the new command with an argument. If you need also to define a user level command, you can do with the same technique:

```
\newcommand{\iitthesis@thesisdatafield}[1]{%
  \long\@namedef{#1}##1{\@namedef{iitthesis@#1}{##1}}}
```

In this case saying

```
\iitthesis@thesisdatafield{authorEnglish}
```

would define the command `\authorEnglish` so that if the user types

```
\authorEnglish{A. U. Thor}
```

the effect would be as if doing

```
\def\iitthesis@authorEnglish{A. U. Thor}
```

The `\long` prefix to `\@namedef` causes `\long\def` to be executed, so the argument can span one or more paragraphs.

This technique is employed by the LaTeX kernel, where `\author{A. U. Thor}` actually defines `\@author` expanding eventually to "A. U. Thor".

Comment: You might want to mention the `makeatletter...\makeatother` issue and add it around the code.

Comment: @PeterGrill The OP is quite clear about doing this in a class file, where `@` is a letter.

Answer (score 9):

As in the other question, you need to use `\csname .. \endcsname` to build the macro name and `\expandafter` to expand it to that name before you are using `\newcommand` (or similar) to define that macro.
Simply append the optional parameter argument after `\endcsname`.

```
\newcommand{\iitthesis@thesisdatafield}[2]{%
   \expandafter\newcommand\csname iitthesis@#1\endcsname{#2}%
   \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname iitthesis@#1\endcsname{##1}}%
}
```

Note that you need to double the `#` for the argument in the inner macro, so that it is clear it isn't the first argument of the outer one.

There is the `\@namedef{<name>}<parameter text>{<macro code>}` macro which does basically the same, but using the TeX primitive `\def`, not LaTeX's `\newcommand`. The basic difference is that it doesn't check if the macro exists yet and defines it in any case and that you have to list the parameters in plain form: `#1` instead of `[1]`, `#1#2` instead of `[2]` etc.

Comment: You might want to mention the `makeatletter...\makeatother` issue and add it around the code.

Comment: @PeterGrill: The OP stated the code is for a class, so this is not required.