# Using a variable as a package setting within a class

Tags: documentclass-writing

I have defined a new class. Within this class, I am calling on the hyperref package, and I set the following options:

```
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup 
{
  pdfauthor={...},
  pdfsubject={...},
  pdftitle={...},
}
```

Now, I have defined certain variables within this class (which I can call with `\variablename{}`). However, if I use these within this package, as part of the option settings, then this fails (undefined control sequence). Am I not using the right syntax?

```
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup 
{
  pdfauthor={\variablename{}},
  pdfsubject={\variablename{}},
  pdftitle={\variablename{}},
}
```

I've read these questions ([variable-name \newcommand with parameters within another \newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34697/variable-name-newcommand-with-parameters-within-another-newcommand) and [Defining a newcommand, with variable name, inside another newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/defining-a-newcommand-with-variable-name-inside-another-newcommand)), but they are about newcommands... this is rather a regular package (hyperref) that I'm including, so I'm hoping it does not need to be this complicated)...

Comment: How have you defined `\variablename`? Can you post an MWE?

Answer (score 1):

The following combination correctly sets the `pdfauthor` to "Andrew":

`test.sty`:

```
\newcommand{\myname}{Andrew}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\myname}}
```

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{test}

\begin{document}
Text.
\end{document}
```

It is important not to call the `\hypersetup` command before the variable `\myname` has been set.  However, it could be put in an `\AtBeginDocument` command to delay processing to the that point.