# Define macro for sequence/list/tuple macros

Tags: macros, expansion

I would like to define a macro for defining further macros to display sequences/lists/tuples of elements by specifying the following parameters:

1. The name of the new command.
2. What to display for an empty sequence/list/tuple.
3. How to open a singleton sequence/list/tuple.
4. How to close a singleton sequence/list/tuple.
5. How to open a sequence/list/tuple with more than one element.
6. How to close a sequence/list/tuple with more than one element.
7. What to display as separating object between two elements in the sequence/list/tuple.

I had a look at the following questions and corresponding answers:

- [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter)
- [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/what-exactly-do-csname-and-endcsname-do)
- [Defining a newcommand, with variable name, inside another newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/defining-a-newcommand-with-variable-name-inside-another-newcommand?lq=1)
- [variable-name \newcommand with parameters within another \newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34697/variable-name-newcommand-with-parameters-within-another-newcommand)

So I tried to code my command and came up with the following two versions (the second one is outcommented in the code below). Unfortunately, none of them works and I cannot figure out what the problem is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\definelistcommand}[7]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname @start#1\endcsname{\expandafter\@ifnextchar\csname @stop#1\endcsname{#2\csname @end#1\endcsname}{\csname @first#1\endcsname}}%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname @first#1\endcsname[1]{\expandafter\@ifnextchar\csname @stop#1\endcsname{#3##1#4\csname @end#1\endcsname}{#5##1\csname @next#1\endcsname}}%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname @next#1\endcsname[1]{#7##1\expandafter\@ifnextchar\csname @stop#1\endcsname{#6\csname @end#1\endcsname}{\csname @next#1\endcsname}}%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname @end#1\endcsname[1]{}% consumes the \stop command
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{\csname @start#1\endcsname##1\csname @stop#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

% \makeatletter 
% \edef\definelistcommand#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
% \noexpand\newcommand\expandafter\noexpand\csname @start#1\endcsname{\noexpand\@ifnextchar\expandafter\noexpand\csname @stop#1\endcsname{#2\expandafter\noexpand\csname @end#1\endcsname}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname @first#1\endcsname}}%
% \noexpand\newcommand\expandafter\noexpand\csname @first#1\endcsname[1]{\noexpand\@ifnextchar\expandafter\noexpand\csname @stop#1\endcsname{#3##1#4\expandafter\noexpand\csname @end#1\endcsname}{#5##1\expandafter\noexpand\csname @next#1\endcsname}}%
% \noexpand\newcommand\expandafter\noexpand\csname @next#1\endcsname[1]{#7##1\noexpand\@ifnextchar\expandafter\noexpand\csname @stop#1\endcsname{#6\expandafter\noexpand\csname @end#1\endcsname}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname @next#1\endcsname}}%
% \noexpand\newcommand\expandafter\noexpand\csname @end#1\endcsname[1]{}% consumes the \stop command
% \noexpand\newcommand\expandafter\noexpand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{\expandafter\noexpand\csname @start#1\endcsname##1\expandafter\noexpand\csname @stop#1\endcsname}%
% }
% \makeatother

\definelistcommand{mylist}{empty}{[}{]}{(}{)}{,}

\begin{document}

\mylist{{a}{b}{c}}

\mylist{{a}{b}}

\mylist{a}

\mylist{{b}}

\mylist{}

\end{document}
```

The desired output would be:

```
(a,b,c)
(a,b)
[a]
[b]
empty
```

For the first version, I get this error message:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \let
l.27 \mylist{{a}{b}{c}}
```

For the second version, I get this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.27 \mylist
            {{a}{b}{c}}
```

What are the errors in my commands and how would a correct solution work?

EDIT (to point future readers to the fact that the accepted answer is not the only interesting one):
Although I accepted the answer by Christian Hupfer (since it contains an explanation and fix for my attempt), the other answers also contain valuable contributions. In particular, I will use egreg's solution as it allows a key-value pair specification of my desired parameters. Unfortunately, I cannot accept two answers.

Comment: Wouldn't this be much easier with `etoolbox` `\listadd` etc. or with `expl3` and its `clist` or `seq` features?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not very familiar with etoolbox. If you have a simpler solution with these, just put that as an answer.

Comment: I'll try, but I am not sure about your purposes. You want a mapper, basically?

Comment: I have several list-like structures and would like to have one command for each of these structures by which I can easily define how these structures are displayed (e.g., a sequence of substitutions should be displayed differently than a sequence of states, but each sequence of substitutions should be displayed in the same format). Since the list-like structure is what these structures have in common, I would like to define one generic command for all of them rather than defining several commands in more or less the same way.

Comment: While there are already good solutions how to define the macro by different approaches, I would still like to know why my attempts fail and how to fix them. Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: I think the error is  `\expandafter\@ifnextchar\csname \@stop#1\endcsname` -- it does not expand correctly. Do you really need a `\@stop#1` or will a general `\@stopthis` do as well? (It works with `\@stopthis`, by the way.

Comment: I've added a working version with a global `\@stoplist` command at the end of my solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `expl3` version with `seq` variables.

The command `\NewListCommand` declares the command list macro named like the first argument and uses a global `seq` variable with some prefix, see `\g_cryingshadow_mynewlist_seq` etc.

This is filled by the `\mynewlist` command and the content displayed depending on the content of the other parameters from #3 to #6. The 7th. parameter is used as a delimiter

Some notes: The `empty` parameter could be an optional one.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewListCommand}{mmmmmmm}{%
  \seq_new:c {g_cryingshadow_#1_seq} % Make a new sequence
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{m}{%
    \seq_gclear:c {g_cryingshadow_#1_seq}% Clear the sequence
    \seq_gclear:N \l_tmpa_seq % Clear a temporary `\l_tmpa_seq
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {} {##1} % Split the sequence into tokens. 
    \seq_set_eq:cN {g_cryingshadow_#1_seq} \l_tmpa_seq % copy the temporary sequence to the real one → this would not be necessary if the sequence is not be used outside 
    \seq_if_empty:cTF {g_cryingshadow_#1_seq} {%
      #2% Checked --> is empty
    }{%
      % Display the various styles
      \int_case:nn { \seq_count:c {g_cryingshadow_#1_seq} }
      {%
        {1} {#3      \seq_use:cnnn {g_cryingshadow_#1_seq} {,} {#7} {#7} #4}
      }%
      \int_compare:nNnT { \seq_count:c {g_cryingshadow_#1_seq}}  > 1 {%
        #5      \seq_use:cnnn {g_cryingshadow_#1_seq} {#7} {#7} {#7} #6
      }
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\NewListCommand{mynewlist}{empty}{[}{]}{(}{)}{,}


\begin{document}

\mynewlist{{A}{B}{C}}

\mynewlist{{A}{B}}

\mynewlist{{a}}

\mynewlist{}


\mynewlist{{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}}


Astronomer's alphabet:

\mynewlist{{Oh}{be}{a}{fine}{girl}{kiss}{me}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Here's the working version for usual LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\def\definelistcommand#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%

  \expandafter\def\csname @firstinlist#1\endcsname##1{%
    \@ifnextchar\@stoplist{%
      #3##1#4\@endlist%
    }{%
      #5##1\csname @nextlist#1\endcsname%
    }%
  }

  \expandafter\def\csname @nextlist#1\endcsname##1{%
    \@ifnextchar\@stoplist{%
      #7##1#6\@endlist%
    }{%
      #7##1\csname @nextlist#1\endcsname%
    }%
  }


  \expandafter\def\csname @startlist#1\endcsname##1{%
    \@ifnextchar\@stoplist{%
      #3##1#4\@endlist%
    }{%
      \csname @firstinlist#1\endcsname##1% 
    }%
  }

  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname##1{%
    \ifblank{##1}{%
      #2%
    }{%
      \csname @startlist#1\endcsname##1\@stoplist%
    }%
  }
}

\def\@endlist#1{}


\definelistcommand{mycmd}{empty}{[}{]}{(}{)}{,}

\definelistcommand{othercmd}{empty}{\textbraceleft}{\textbraceright}{(}{)}{+}

\begin{document}


\makeatother

\mycmd{{A}{B}{C}}

\mycmd{A}

\mycmd{{A}{B}}

\mycmd{}

\othercmd{{O}{B}}

\othercmd{{O}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain your solution a little bit? I'm not very familiar with xparse etc. and would like to get an idea how and why this works as it does (and maybe then also get an idea why my solution does not).

Comment: @cryingshadow: I wished I could explain why your versions do not work, at the moment I can't. I'll add some explanations about the code into the code

Comment: @cryingshadow: I'll use `xparse` and `expl3` very frequently, although I am no expert of course -- but I can recommend it, `xparse` itself is easy to learn

Comment: @cryingshadow: You constantly call `\csname @stop#1\endcsname` This is never defined (so the result is `\relax`.)

Comment: True, but it should never be executed - it should be consumed by the `@end#1` command.

Comment: @cryingshadow: After looking into your code again, I think that your code does not look far enough to see the `\@stop` etc. really

Comment: What do you mean by "does not look far enough" and how could that be fixed?

Answer (score 9):

You can try this macro:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\definelistcommand#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
   \expandafter\def\csname\string#1:list\endcsname##1{%
      \ifcase##1 #2\or#3\or#4\or#5\or#6\or#7\fi}%
   \def#1{\dolist#1}%
}
\def\dolist#1#2{\tmpnum=0 \def\tmp{}%
   \def\listcommand{\csname\string#1:list\endcsname}%
   \dolistA#2\end}
\def\dolistA#1{%
   \ifx\end#1%
      \ifnum\tmpnum=0 \listcommand0%
      \else\ifnum\tmpnum=1 \listcommand1\tmp\listcommand2%
      \else \listcommand3\tmp\listcommand4%
      \fi\fi
   \else\edef\tmp{\ifx\tmp\empty\else\tmp\listcommand5\fi#1}%
      \advance\tmpnum by1
      \expandafter\dolistA\fi
}

\definelistcommand \mylist {empty} [](),

\mylist{{a}{b}{c}}

\mylist{{a}{b}}

\mylist{a}

\mylist{{b}}

\mylist{}
```

Explanation. The `\definelistcommand\foo` defines two control sequences. First one `\\foo:list` as `\ifcase`. It expands the appropriate declared parameter: `\\foo:list0` expnads to `nothing`, `\\foo:list1` to `[` etc. Second defined control sequence is `\foo`. This is macro `\dolist\foo`.

The usage of `\foo{text}` expands to `\dolist\foo{text}`. This macro resets `\tmp` to empty, `\tmpnum` to zero and saves `\listcommand` as `\\foo:list`. Then it runs `\dolistA text\end`.

The `\dolistA` reads the items of the text repeatedly. It saves these items to the `\tmp` macro using `\edef\tmp`. If `\tmp` is not empty then the comma (alias `\listcommand5`) is added between the previous contents and the next item `#1`. The `\tmpnum` counts the number of items. When `\end` is reached then `\tmp` is printed depending on the `\tmpnum` value.

Note that we need not any external package and we can declare the list-like macro very simply.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Could you explain a little bit how it works? It seems you are using a counter for the number of elements and that several further commands are defined which might have conflicting names with other user-defined commands.

Comment: @cryingshadow If there will be more votes then I'll add the explanation. I see more votes in LaTeX 3 solution (which is absurd language), but solutions based only on classical TeX is not evaluated here. And to conflicting names with other user-defined commands: what is `\hbox`, `\vskip` etc? They are conflicting names with user-defined commands too.

Comment: I can only vote once... ;) I am just interested in how it works and what to keep in mind when using it (that is what the part on conflicting names is about - it was not intended as a criticism against your solution).

Answer (score 6):

Rather than a long list of arguments, I think it's better to use a key-value syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definelistcommand}{mm}
 {% #1 is the command name, #2 is the key-value setup
  % clear the temporary property list
  \prop_clear:N \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop
  \keys_set:nn { cryingshadow/list } { #2 }
  % check if left-single or right-single have been set
  \prop_if_in:NnF \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop { left-single }
   {
    \prop_put:Nnx \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop { left-single }
     { \prop_item:Nn \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop { left } }
   }
  \prop_if_in:NnF \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop { right-single }
   {
    \prop_put:Nnx \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop { right-single }
     { \prop_item:Nn \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop { right } }
   }
  % allocate a specific property list and make it equal to the temporary one
  \prop_new:c { g_cryingshadow_list_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_eq:cN { g_cryingshadow_list_#1_prop } \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop
  % define the runtime macro to call the generic one with the current name as argument
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #1 } ##1 { \cryingshadow_list_print:nn { #1 } { ##1 } }
 }

% allocate some variables
\prop_new:N \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop
\seq_new:N \l_cryingshadow_list_input_seq

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cryingshadow_list_put:nn
 {
  \prop_put:Nnn \l_cryingshadow_list_temp_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cryingshadow_list_item:nn
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_cryingshadow_list_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

% define the keys
\keys_define:nn { cryingshadow/list }
 {
  empty .code:n = \__cryingshadow_list_put:nn { empty } { #1 },
  left-single .code:n = \__cryingshadow_list_put:nn { left-single } { #1 },
  right-single .code:n = \__cryingshadow_list_put:nn { right-single } { #1 },
  left .code:n = \__cryingshadow_list_put:nn { left } { #1 },
  right .code:n = \__cryingshadow_list_put:nn { right } { #1 },
  delimiter .code:n = \__cryingshadow_list_put:nn { delimiter } { #1 },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cryingshadow_list_print:nn
 {
  % split the input into items at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_cryingshadow_list_input_seq { , } { #2 }
  % branch between empty or single and multiple items
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_cryingshadow_list_input_seq = 1 }
   {
    % if the sequence has just one item it could be empty
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
     { \__cryingshadow_list_item:nn { #1 } { empty } }
     {
      \__cryingshadow_list_item:nn { #1 } { left-single }
      #2
      \__cryingshadow_list_item:nn { #1 } { right-single }
     }
   }
   {
    % otherwise it has multiple items
    \__cryingshadow_list_item:nn { #1 } { left }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_cryingshadow_list_input_seq { \__cryingshadow_list_item:nn { #1 } { delimiter } }
    \__cryingshadow_list_item:nn { #1 } { right }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definelistcommand{firstlist}{
  empty=empty,
  left-single=[,
  right-single=],
  left=(,
  right=),
  delimiter={, },
}
\definelistcommand{secondlist}{
  empty=nothing,
  left=\{,
  right=\},
  delimiter={--},
}

\begin{document}

\firstlist{A,B,C}

\firstlist{A,B}

\firstlist{a}

\firstlist{}

\secondlist{A,B,C}

\secondlist{A,B}

\secondlist{a}

\secondlist{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How does this work?

The `\definelistcommand` first sets up a property list specific for the list command to be defined, where to store the various items (outer delimiters, inner delimiters, what to do for the empty case); then it defines the macro to call a generic function for producing the output.

The property list is supplied the values by examining the second argument. If `left-single` or `right-single` are not specified, the values for `left` or `right` are supplied.

At call time, the generic macro takes the values from the specific property list, splits the argument at commas and then branches: if the argument is blank, the value for the case is printed; if there's only one item, the `left-single` and `right-single` outer delimiters are used; otherwise the `left` and `right` ones, with the inner delimiter between items.

Comment: I really like the idea of key-value pairs. Seems I have to dive into xparse and friends for sophisticated macros...

Comment: @cryingshadow You can also easily supplement the list of keys, for instance you can add a key for the list separator at run time; or maybe define a constant property list with default values, so you can specify only the ones that are to be changed; you can add a check for the “single” keys and, if missing, use the “nonsingle” ones.

Comment: @cryingshadow I made some changes along the lines of my previous comment.

Comment: I just noted one thing in this solution that is problematic in my setting: It seems that this command "breaks out" of math mode. So I cannot just use it within math mode as I can, e.g., with the solution by @wipet.

Comment: @cryingshadow I have no problem and, no, it doesn't do differently in text or math mode; of course, if you plan to use `\langle` and `\rangle` as outer delimiters and the macro in math mode, you shouldn't say `left=$\langle$`, but `left=\langle` (or `left=\ensuremath{\langle}`).

Comment: Never mind. I had a different error and just the error message was confusing. Yes, your solution also works perfectly in math mode.