# \newcommand with variable name

Tags: macros

I am typesetting a long mathematical text (lecture notes), in which I use the alphabets

```
\mathbb A
\mathcal A
\mathfrak A
```

very often, so I decided to name them

```
\A \sA \fA
```

(For bb A, script A, fraktur A resp.). Now I want to shorten my preamble by creating a helper

```
\newcommand{\mathletter}[1]{%
    \newcommand{\#1}{\mathbb #1}
    \newcommand{\s#1}{\mathcal #1}
    \newcommand{\f#1}{\mathfrak #1}
}
```

which doesn't work since the \#1 etc. seem to not be expanded.
How can I wirte a macro which defines those three commands given a single letter as input?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is strange. Why not define 3 new commands? If your code works what would you type: `\mathletter{A}`?

Comment: Because that means 26*3 = 78 lines of code vs. 36+5 = 41 lines, about half and much more readable than a bunch of `\newcommand{\X}{\mathbb X}` lines

Comment: You might need to keep in mind that some commands are already defined (for example `\O`).

Comment: @Sigur No, latex complains about `LaTeX Error: Command \# already defined.` when doing that.

Comment: 78? Would you define new commands for all letters? You are remaking the wheel.

Comment: @Snicksie Thanks for the heads-up, since I prefer `\emptyset`, I can live without `\O`, so I'll just redefine it

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/defining-a-newcommand-with-variable-name-inside-another-newcommand?rq=1

Comment: @AlexR `\o` is *not* empty set. These very short names does not help much in the readability of your source code.

Comment: @Snicksie Looks very promising, I'll try it out.

Comment: @daleif I am TeXing math equations with lots and lots of mathbb, I have found the code to become much more readable by defining those short commands, plus the additional time save on typing them out. But that's up to preference I guess.

Comment: Does this suffice: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\B#1{\mathbb #1}
\def\C#1{\mathcal #1}
\def\F#1{\mathfrak #1}
\begin{document}
$\B A \C A \F A $
\end{document}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's also a good way of doing it, but I don't want to retype 35 pages of TeX :D

Comment: @AlexR, you don't need to retype. You can use Find/Replace tools.

Comment: @AlexR, my dislike is the very short names. Over time I think it is a lot better to name macros for what they are used for instead of forcing, say, coauthors to guess what a specific macro is used for.

Comment: @daleif Agreed, but those are only for my personal use, so there are no coauthors who have to guess anything :)

Comment: You say "I don't want to retype 35 pages of TeX", but I think any good editor should be able to do a global search and replace that would take care of 99% of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks to @Snicksie, I have been able to come up with the following:

Note that this is not really "beautiful" and that it overwrites the commands
    \H,\L,\O,\P,\S but I have confirmed that I need none of them and "manually" undefined them so I get errors when I oversee any other commands.

```
\newcommand{\mathletter}[1]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\mathbb #1}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname s#1\endcsname{\mathcal #1}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname f#1\endcsname{\mathfrak #1}
}%
\let\H\undefined
\let\L\undefined
\let\O\undefined
\let\P\undefined
\let\S\undefined
\mathletter A
\mathletter B
\mathletter C
...
\mathletter Z
```

> Another very elegant solution, thanks to @StevenB.Segelets is to define:

```
\def\B#1{\mathbb #1}
\def\C#1{\mathcal #1}
\def\F#1{\mathfrak #1}
```

And use those slighly different commands then. This doesn't redefine any existing macros and therefor is probably a cleaner solution, but requires to change previous syntax (`\A, \sA, \fA`) in all documents and thus requires some "rewriting".