# Using command parameters to use another command

Tags: macros

Say I have written two commands, CommandA and CommandB. I wish to have a third command that takes inputs to determines which of the two previous commands to execute. Very naively this how I would try and accomplish this as shown below, however, it does not work.

```
\newcommand{CommandA}{
    \hspace{5mm}
}
\newcommand{CommandB}{
    \vspace{5mm}
}
\newcommand{C}[1]{
    \Command#1
}
```

So if I call `\C{A}`, as written I would really execute `\CommandA`.

Comment: Note that `\CommandA` will make a space considerably larger that `5mm` since it has a word space either side (so typically you'll get around 2/3 of an em extra space unless you put `%` at ends of the lines in thse definitions.

Comment: Note that you have to use backslashes in `\newcommand{\CommandA}`.  You need a `\csname .. \endcsname` construct: `\newcommand{\C}[1]{\csname Command#1\endcsname}`

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, I didn't know that and explains some funny spacing I am getting in my commands.

And Thanks @ArashEsbati, I've already implemented the first answer and got it to work. Originally I was trying to use `\csname .. \endcsname` but I failed to use the correct syntax it seems, thanks for showing how to properly use it. Also, yes completely failed to post correct code—sorry about that.

Comment: See also: [macros - Defining a newcommand, with variable name, inside another newcommand - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/defining-a-newcommand-with-variable-name-inside-another-newcommand)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a normal user, this is probably the easiest to understand

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\CommandA}{%
    \hspace{5mm}%
}
\newcommand{\CommandB}{%
    \vspace{5mm}%
}
\newcommand\C[1]{%
   \csuse{Command#1}%
}
```

`\csuse` builds a macro name, and calls it

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense to define *families* of such commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineobject}{mm}
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_garth_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_garth_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\getobject}{mm}
 {% #1 = object name, #2 = variable or string
  \prop_item:cf { g_garth_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { cf }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineobject{C}{
  A=\hspace{5mm},
  B=\vspace{5mm}
}
\newcommand{\C}[1]{\getobject{C}{#1}}

\begin{document}

X\C{A}Y\C{B}

XYZ

\end{document}
```

[image]

This might turn to be useful for the similar problem in [Can you create concatenate variable names in LaTex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463168/4427)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineobject}{mm}
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_garth_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_garth_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\getobject}{mm}
 {% #1 = object name, #2 = variable or string
  \prop_item:cf { g_garth_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { cf }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineobject{fun}{
  A={$s(t) = 12t^2 -7t + 16$},
  B={$s(t) = 16t^2 +3t + 10$},
  C={$s(t) = 12t^2 + t + 10.$}
}

\newcommand{\exam}{A}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question
The position of an object moving along a straight line is given by 
\getobject{fun}{\exam}. Find the average velocity of the object over 
the interval $[1,1+h]$ where $h>0$ is a real number.

\renewcommand{\exam}{B} % just for testing

\question
The position of an object moving along a straight line is given by 
\getobject{fun}{\exam}. Find the average velocity of the object over 
the interval $[1,1+h]$ where $h>0$ is a real number.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The second question has a modified `\exam` just to test whether the expected output is obtained. You can define as many objects as you want. If one has just one variable `\exam`, it also makes sense to define a shorthand:

```
\newcommand{\obj}[1]{\getobject{#1}{\exam}}
```

and then the calls above can be more simply `\obj{fun}`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\name{}%
\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
   \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%

\name\newcommand{CommandA}{%
    \hspace{5mm}%
}

\name\newcommand{CommandB}{%
    \vspace{5mm}%
}

\name\newcommand{C}[1]{%
    \name{Command#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\hbox{\hbox{X}\C{A}\hbox{X}}%
\C{B}%
\hbox{\hbox{X}\C{A}\hbox{X}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]