# Can you create concatenate variable names in LaTex?

Tags: variable

I would like to create variables to hold strings like f(x)=3x+1 to be inputted into an exam questions.

I can create variables like \funA, \funB, … et cetera. The problem is how do I reference them using A, B, … et cetera.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

% conditional statements
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\exam}{A}

\newcommand{\funA}{$s(t) = 12t^2 -7t + 16$}
\newcommand{\funB}{$s(t) = 16t^2 +3t + 10$}
\newcommand{\funC}{$s(t) = 12t^2 + t + 10.$}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question % I would like \fun\exam to return \funA when \exam = a. Sadly it doesn't 

The position of an object moving along a straight line is given by \fun\exam. Find the average velocity of the object over the interval $[1,1+h]$ where $h>0$ is a real number.

\question % this works but is a lot to write when accommodating 10 stored functions

\ifthenelse{\equal{\exam}{A}}
    {
        \newcommand{\function}{$s(t) = 12t^2 -7t + 16.$}
    }
    {
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\exam}{B}}
            {
                \newcommand{\function}{$s(t) = 16t^2 +3t + 10.$}
            }
            {
                \newcommand{\function}{$s(t) = 12t^2 + t + 10.$}
            }
    }

The position of an object moving along a straight line is given by \function\ Find the average velocity of the object over the interval $[1,1+h]$ where $h>0$ is a real number.

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\csname fun\exam\endcsname`

Comment: I added an answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX allows you to reference `c`ontrol `s`equence `name`s using a `\csname`...`\endcsname` pair. Any command inside this `\csname`...`\endcsname` pair will be expanded (*i.e.*: replaced by its meaning) until only unexpandable tokens are left, then TeX creates a control sequence out of the contents passed to `\csname`...`\endcsname`.

For instance, if you have `\newcommand{\exam}{A}`, then `\csname funA\endcsname` and `\csname fun\exam\endcsname` will both expand to `\funA`. You can create a wrapper command to avoid writing `\csname`...`\endcsname` every single time:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\newcommand{\exam}{A}

\newcommand{\fun}[1]{\csname fun#1\endcsname}
% or:
% \newcommand{\fun}{\csname fun\exam\endcsname}, then use just \fun instead of \fun\exam
\newcommand{\funA}{$s(t) = 12t^2 -7t + 16$}
\newcommand{\funB}{$s(t) = 16t^2 +3t + 10$}
\newcommand{\funC}{$s(t) = 12t^2 + t + 10$}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question

The position of an object moving along a straight line is given by \fun\exam. Find the average velocity of the object over the interval $[1,1+h]$ where $h>0$ is a real number.

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: LaTeX has `\@nameuse` but unfortunately it has a `@` in its name...

Comment: @jfbu And there's `expl3`'s `\use:c` too, but if you tilt your head to the left it looks too sad ;)

Comment: @jfbu and @PhelypeOleinik: And `etoolbox`'s `\csuse`, if we're compiling a list :).

Comment: @Circumscribe good point!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik you can tilt to your right :)

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik, thank you so much. This is perfect. I have wanted to do this forever...couldn't find a solution anywhere.