# How to define newcommand* with a variable name?

Tags: csname, renewcommand

I'm trying this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo\endcsname{}
\expandafter\newcommand*\csname bar\endcsname{}
\end{document}
```

The second `\newcommand*` doesn't work:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \csname already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.4 \expandafter\newcommand*\csname b
                                     ar\endcsname{}
```

I failed to find a hint at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/defining-a-newcommand-with-variable-name-inside-another-newcommand).

Comment: The star is not part of the macro name, but is an argumet (`\@ifstar`)  You may need `\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname...`.

Comment: However, the name `\bar` needs to change, because it is of course already defined in LaTeX.

Comment: At least it would give a different error message ;-)

Comment: @JohnKormylo if you make it an answer, I will choose it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\newcommand*` is *two* tokens, so you need one more `\expandafter` to jump over the `*`, so

```
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname foo\endcsname{<replacement text>}
```

On the other hand, it's quite pointless to use `\newcommand*` for a parameterless macro; if you want to check whether a macro defined with `\newcommand` has empty replacement text, then you can use the `\ifdefempty` or `\ifcsempty` tests from `etoolbox` or define your own version of an empty “long” macro

```
\newcommand\yegorempty{}
```

and then macros defined with `\newcommand` with empty replacement text will be equal to `\yegorempty` if tested with `\ifx`.

Answer (score 9):

It's worth noting that there are internal LaTeX commands for this purpose:

```
 \@namedef{NAME}{...}
```

defines `\NAME` as a command. These are thin wrappers around the TeX primitive `\def`, so if you want to have arguments, you need to use the plain syntax, e.g., for a three-argument command:

```
 \@namedef{NAME}#1#2#3{...}
```

This would be equivalent¹ to `\newcommand*{\NAME}[3]{...}` or `\NewDocumentCommand{\NAME}{mmm}{...}` `\newcommand` without the `*` or `\NewDocumentCommand` specifying `+m` instead of `m` would be accomplished using:

```
 \long\@namedef{NAME}...
```

Depending on your needs, this might be a more appropriate method.

And to expand on John Kormylo's answer, here's the much simpler² equivalent that uses `\NewDocumentCommand` instead of `\newcommand`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewNameDocumentCommand}{m}
   {%
     \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname
   }
```

---

1. Not exactly in that `\newcommand` checks to see if the command exists with `\@ifdefinable` before it actually does the definition, while `\@namedef` doesn't care.
2. Mostly because `\NewDocumentCommand` uses a more flexible method of distinguishing between long and short arguments than `\newcommand` and thus doesn't have a `*` form. That said, if we wanted to precisely replicate John's definition with `\newcommand` for the definitions, we could write:³

   ```
   \NewDocumentCommand{\Newcommand}{sm}
     {%
       \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
         {\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname #2\endcsname}%
         {\expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname}%
     }
   ```
3. Comparing the two definitions should make it clear why I'm such a big proponent of `\NewDocumentCommand` over `\newcommand`, especially since the former has been part of the LaTeX kernel for almost a year now.

Answer (score 4):

I also created `\Newcommand` to apply the `\csname` automatically.  It turns out that `\newcommand` converts `\foo` to `\\foo` internally, so having the name does not save any steps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo\endcsname{test 1}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname foobar\endcsname{test 2}

\makeatletter
\def\Newcommand{\@ifstar\@Newcommandstar\@Newcommand}
\def\@Newcommand #1{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname}
\def\@Newcommandstar #1{\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname #1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\Newcommand{Foo}{test 3}
\Newcommand*{Foobar}{test 4}

\begin{document}
\foo

\foobar

\Foo

\Foobar
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you avoid LaTeX syntax and use directly TeX syntax, things are more simple:

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}

\sdef{foo}{test}
\long\sdef{Foo}{test2}

\meaning\foo, % normal macro \foo expands to test 
\meaning\Foo. % long macro \Foo expands to test2

\bye
```

Of course, you can use `\sdef`-ed macros with parameters like in `\def` primitive or you can use `\global` prefix.