# dynamically call acronyms

Tags: macros, acronyms, glossaries-extra

When I call the acronym "CAD" statically with my own command `accad` I can call the corresponding acronym indirectly without a problem.

But if I try to call it dynamically with the (in the MWE) commented out sections the compilation apparently stops at the definition of `defGLS`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{ac:cad}{CAD}{Computer Aided Design}

\newcommand{\accad}{\gls{ac:cad}}

%\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\defGLS}[1]{
%   \@namedef{#1}{\gls{ac:#1}}
%\makeatother

%\defGLS{cad}

\begin{document}

\accad

%\cad

\printglossaries
    
\end{document}
```

I tried to use `\expandafter` in different positions in the line of `\@namedef` (before and/or after it as well as before `\gls...`) but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

First define a `\creator` of new commands.

```
\create{<command name>}
```

Then call it to create the new commands with the desired result.
In this example it is done 3 times, once for each defined acronym.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{cad}{CAD}{Computer Aided Design}    
\newacronym{AC}{AC}{Alternating Current}    
\newacronym{saas}{SaaS}{Software as a Service}  

%********************************************* added
\newcommand{\create}[1]{%  \create{<command name>}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\gls{#1}\par}   
}   

\create{cad}
\create{AC}
\create{saas}

%************************************************
    
\begin{document}   
    
    \textbf{First time}
    
    \verb|\cad|:    \cad
    
    \verb|\AC|: \AC
    
    \verb|\saas|:   \saas
    
    \bigskip
    
    \textbf{Second time}
    
    \verb|\cad|:    \cad
    
    \verb|\AC|: \AC
    
    \verb|\saas|:   \saas

    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: b]

Your code using `\@namedef` will work after correcting the definition of `\defGLS` (a missing brace)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defGLS}[1]{%
   \@namedef{#1}{\gls{#1}}%
}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatother

\defGLS{cad}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. With your code I can call the acronym indirectly with the `\defGLS` command but unfortunately not with the `\cad` command I intended to create in my MWE. Is there any possibility to define this command `\cad` inside the `\defGLS` command?

Comment: @Lukas Please explain me the purpose of `\cad` and its intended output. Thank you!

Comment: The command `\cad` which is dynamically created with `\glsDEF{cad}` should call the acronym `\gls{ac:cad}`. If this works as intended I can create different commands in relation to the respective acronym.

Comment: The base solution with `namedef` I got from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34709/244141 and tried to adapt it for acronyms.

Comment: @Lukas  Please see the updated the answer.